# Wireless problems

Tags: wireless, networking

I have ubuntu 14.04 and haven't had any problems at all, but yesterday I got a new router and suddenly it can't find the network on the network list, and if I go in to settings>Network>Wireless it shows the Network but says it's out of range.
I have surfed the web and tryed countless of options, but nothing works.
Is it possible to make it work without reinstalling ubuntu from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to settings in router, if you have an old laptop it might have difficulty at communicating with router.

open your router interface in a browser

192.168.2.1

navigate to wireless>wireless net settings and pick up 802.11b then save and restart router.

Comment: My other laptop and Ipad can both find and connect to the wireless router. I changed the SSID on the new router and since then ubuntu cant find it. I tried deleting old network and connect to the new SSID manually and nothing happens. I tried reinstalling ubuntu and it still cant find the network. Its pretty weird.

Comment: Do you use encryption in router?

Comment: No, and all devices can find and connect. Only ubuntu can't find the Network.

Comment: Can you tell us what your internet provider changed ? Was it set to wireless N, and your Ubuntu only support B and G ?

Comment: I guess we will never know !

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the name of the wifi network in the router ? (It's called SSID).  A new router will have a new network name. You can either configure the SSID to be the same as the old one, or you can delete the wifi network from Ubuntu and connect to the new one. I would suggest deleting the wifi from Ubuntu, configuring your SSID and password on the router, and connecting to this new wifi.

Comment: My other laptop and Ipad can both find and connect to the wireless router. I changed the SSID on the new router and since then ubuntu cant find it. I tried deleting old network and connect to the new SSID manually and nothing happens. I tried reinstalling ubuntu and it still cant find the network. Its pretty weird.

Comment: What channel is the router set to. Is it 13 ? Is it auto ? Is it broadcasting SSID or have you set it as a hidden network ? Make sure its not a hidden network and try channel 3, 7 or 11. Does that work ?

Comment: It is set to auto channel and pick the channel with least frequence to optimize speed and stability. The Network is not hidden. The part that gets me is that all devices can find and connect to the internet, it's only the pc with ubuntu that can find all nearby Networks except my own Network.